# Getting Error when i push session keys session.NoAssociatedValidatorId

Tags: session, poa, keyring, node-key

I'm getting the error
`session.NoAssociatedValidatorId`
while inserting session keys, Although my Explorer is connect to same explorer and Keys are generated by using **RPC->RotateKeys()**.
Any sort of help will be much appreciable.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps your session key is the `ValidatorId` and you need to pass in your validator main account id ([ref](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/1a1c32a1cc7c56e88485f146977ba0fb32026c0a/frame/session/src/lib.rs#L784-L790))?

Comment: @DaanvanderPlas can you please elaborate it more. i did't get your point.

Comment: Which chain are you connecting to?

Comment: @DaanvanderPlas it's Stand alone chain with POA consensus and Unified accounts implementation. you can inspect session keys config and etc here. 
https://github.com/Block-Bird/storage-chain-poa.git

Answer (score 1):

From looking at your configuration; the [`ValidatorId`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/cb450b626ac8e8848db76933e114e57e7cce3e8d/frame/session/src/lib.rs#L39C2-L41) is configured to an `AccountId` and `ValidatorIdOf` is configured to `()`. `ValidatorIdOf` makes the conversion from an `AccountId` to a `ValidatorId` (can be used for controller accounts). What I think is happening in your case is because `ValidatorIdOf` is set to `()` it can't convert the `AccountId`, that is used to sign the `set_keys` transaction, to a (unique) `ValidatorId`.

So you need to configure the `ValidatorIdOf` to something that can convert an `AccountId` to an `AccountId` (because you configured `ValidatorId` to `AccountId`.

If you have a look at [Rococo's configuration](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/09b61286da11921a3dda0a8e4015ceb9ef9cffca/runtime/rococo/src/lib.rs#L336-L342),  you can see that the conversion is just returning the `AccountId` that is taken as input (you then don't have the ability for controller accounts).